# Menu Disappears on Category Pages

Tags: menus, archives

I have a site whose navigation disappears on category pages for posts in the ‘post’ post type, but not for posts in any of my custom post types. The ‘post’ post type and post of the custom post types use the same template file for theirs archives and headers – no differences. The menu is using the wp_nav_menu function. Example links below (again, same template files being used):

**Menu:** http://politichicks.tv/column/

**No Menu:** http://politichicks.tv/category/videos

Comment: **Theme Folder:** https://github.com/AlanBreck/Vimes-Child-Theme

**Files of interest:**

https://github.com/AlanBreck/Vimes-Child-Theme/blob/master/header.php

https://github.com/AlanBreck/Vimes-Child-Theme/blob/master/archive.php

Comment: You must have figured this out. What worked? I have the same issue, only on the category page do my menus not show.

Comment: this often happens when a theme or plugin has an incorrectly targeted  [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action. the query modifications intended for the main query are also applied to the query for menu items, causing no items to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but seems that is still unresolved. As @Milo said you may have an incorrect `pre_get_posts` implementation.

Most people do this like this (example):

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type' );

function query_post_type( $query ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
        if ( $post_type ) {
            $post_type = $post_type;
        } else {
            $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', 'post', 'departments' );
        }
        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type );

        return $query;
    }
}
```

But we must change the line: `$post_type = $post_type;` and pass `'nav_menu_item'` to the `$post_type` in order to menu to display, as follow:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type' );
function query_post_type( $query ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
        if ( $post_type ) {
            $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', $post_type );
        } else {
            $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', 'post', 'departments' );
        }
        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type );

        return $query;
    }
}
```

I hope this help people who do this wrong and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I added `$query->is_main_query()` to my if to solve this but your post pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you both! I would never figure it out myself, but makes perfect sense! pre_get_posts is also executed when menu items are being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `wp_nav_menu()` function? here is the [wp_nav_menu reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Instead of this:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' )) {
                                if(!getMainMenu('primary')){
                    /*$backup = $wp_query;
                    $wp_query = NULL;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post'));*/
                    getMainMenu('primary');
                    /*$wp_query = $backup;*/
                }
                            }
```

I wold try this:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' )) {     
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'primary' ))
}
```

Comment: That's essentially what's happening right now, but yes, I've tried explicitly calling wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'primary' ) ). In fact, the code as seen in header.php is a response to the wp_nav_menu() not working.